# how to point from Gatsby localhost to Netlify

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-firestore, gatsby, netlify, capacitor

**Technologies used**
I have a TODO app developed in Gatsby, using Firebase Firestore to store the data and read from it

I have used `gatsby-starter-capacitor` project as a starter template. Why? I want my app to run both on iOS and Android.

- What I have right now?
  My local build when using `npx gatsby develop`, I can see the site I have created. I have successfully deployed my app to Netlify as well.
- Also, I can run my app on iOS device, I did `npm run build && npx cap copy ios && npx cap open ios`
- For Firebase, I have created a web app in my Firebase console, and used the details on my Gatsby App template. The Firebase details for the WebApp, e.g. Keys and etc, are in a .env file, which I have declared and uploaded on Netlify Environment Variables section

This launches my app on my iPhone - Fantastic.

Localhost: I can save and read data from Firebase and can see the data appearing saved on Firebase console. (Awesome)

**Problem**
App on iPhone/Netlify loads on a fresh slate, the data is not read from Firebase.

**How** do I productionise my app so my friends can use it when I release it in Appstore. Because, currently when my app runs on an iOS device, it is running on its localhost? or something that I am not sure of. My app is already running on Netlify, how do I connect this iOS project to go to that URL?

Basically, I want users to be able use this app and read/write to Firebase (which currently works on localhost).

Comment: No, I am not. I am using web based Firebase ```import firebase from "firebase/app";
import "firebase/firestore";```

Comment: Can you provide your `.env` configuration? I'm not sure to understand that *"How do I productionise my app so my friends can use it when I release it in Appstore. Because, currently when my app runs on an iOS device, it is running on its localhost? or something that I am not sure of. My app is already running on Netlify, how do I connect this iOS project to go to that URL?"* Can you clarify it? How are your friends running the app?